# Cant export matlab figure using custom font

Tags: matlab, fonts, export, figure

I'm trying to export my plot with Tahoma font :

[image]

However I always end up with the following figure :

[image]

Which is not the font I chose !! can someone tell me why is this happening ?

Also, the legend's font do not change either.

Comment: I think you cannot embed fonts to MATLAB figures normally, you can just use Type1 fonts. Maybe this can help: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-exportfig

Comment: btw: Use TextInterpreter Latex with `$^\circ C$` instead of `*C` --- and why are you writing the units one time in brackets and one time not? Just in case... I suggest to use `[s]` and `[$^\circ C$]` ;-)

Comment: [`xlabel('time [$s$]','Interpreter','LaTex')`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/text_props.html),  `ylabel('temperature [$^\circ C$]','Interpreter','LaTex')`

Comment: @NKN: Turn your comment to an answer. My problem (very same as NLed's) was solved that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For export figures in MATLAB, I highly recommend you to try [**export_fig**](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-exportfig). **WYSIWYG!**

---

This function saves a figure or single axes to one or more vector and/or bitmap file formats, and/or outputs a rasterized version to the workspace, with the following properties:

- Figure/axes reproduced as it appears on screen
- Cropped borders (optional)
- Embedded fonts (pdf only)
- Improved line and grid line styles
- Anti-aliased graphics (bitmap formats)
- Render images at native resolution (optional for bitmap formats)
- Transparent background supported (pdf, eps, png)
- Semi-transparent patch objects supported (png only)
- RGB, CMYK or grayscale output (CMYK only with pdf, eps, tiff)
- Variable image compression, including lossless (pdf, eps, jpg)
- Optionally append to file (pdf, tiff)
- Vector formats: pdf, eps
- Bitmap formats: png, tiff, jpg, bmp, export to workspace

This function is especially suited to exporting figures for use in publications and presentations, because of the high quality and portability of media produced.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot embed fonts to MATLAB figures normally, you can just use Type1 fonts. 
Check this MATLAB function, by Oliver Woodford, maybe it can help: [[Link]](http://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-exportfig)

[image]